# Confused about when to escape metacharacters in pathnames

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, escape-characters

I'm pretty confused about under which circumstances do I need to escape metacharacters in pathnames. Consider the following example:

I'm in the following working directory:

```
$ echo $PWD
/home/helpermethod/foo[b]ar/foo/bar
```

Now I want to strip off everything behind `foo[b]ar`. I'm using parameter substitution to perform this task:/home/helpermethod/foo[b]ar

```
$ path=$PWD
$ basename=foo[b]ar
$ stripped_path=${path%$basename/*}/$basename
```

This doesn't seem to work because the basename string needs to be properly escaped:

```
$ basename=foo\[b\]ar
$ stripped_path=${path%$basename/*}/$basename
```

Okay, now I have the `stripped_path` I was looking for

```
$ echo "$stripped_path"
/home/helpermethod/foo[b]ar
```

But if I now test if this is a valid directory

```
$ [[ -d $stripped_path ]]
```

the `test` command always returns false (i.e. a return value != 0). What's the problem here? Do I need to unescape the `stripped_path`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
stripped_path=${path%"$basename"/*}/$basename
```

Use double quotes to do literal string matching as opposed to pattern matching. One of the cases where you need to quote variables. Another case is in your:

```
echo $PWD
```

above which should have been:

```
echo "$PWD"
```

Or even better:

```
printf '%s\n' "$PWD"
```

Or

```
pwd
```

Comment: +1 The missing quotes really were the problem. Thanks alot!